# Why is the ischecked function for the radio button not working kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

every time I click the calculate button to try and check wether the radio button is checked or not it gives me an error and the app stops responding, the idea is that when the radio button is set to metric then the user enters metric data and if it is set to us then the user enters us data and so on. there is also a problem in changing the hint text so if someone can solve both problems will be much appreciated!

```
BMIactivity.kt:
class BMIactivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var binding: ActivityBmiactivityBinding? = null
    private var rbUSUnits = binding?.rbUSUnits
    private var editTextHeight = binding?.textInputLayoutHeight
    private var editTextWeight = binding?.textInputLayoutWeight

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityBmiactivityBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding?.root)
        setSupportActionBar(binding?.toolbarBmiActivity)
        if (supportActionBar != null) {
            supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
            supportActionBar?.title = "Calculate BMI"
        }

        binding?.toolbarBmiActivity?.setNavigationOnClickListener {
            onBackPressed()
        }

    binding?.btnCalculate?.setOnClickListener{
            if (rbUSUnits!!.isChecked){
                editTextWeight?.hint = "WEIGHT (lbs)"
                editTextHeight?.hint = "HEIGHT (in)"
                usBMI()
            }else{
                metricBMI()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun metricBMI(){
        if(binding?.editTextWeight?.text!!.isEmpty() ||
            binding?.editTextWeight?.text.toString().toFloat() < 10 ||
            binding?.editTextHeight?.text!!.isEmpty() ||
            binding?.editTextHeight?.text.toString().toFloat() < 30){
            Toast.makeText(this@BMIactivity, "Please enter valid data",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }else{
            var metricWeight = binding?.editTextWeight?.text.toString().toFloat()
            var metricHeight = binding?.editTextHeight?.text.toString().toFloat()
            var metricHeightMeters = metricHeight /100
            var metricBMI = ((metricWeight/ (metricHeightMeters*metricHeightMeters))*100).roundToInt().toDouble() / 100
            binding?.tv1?.text = "YOUR BMI"
            binding?.tvBMI?.text = metricBMI.toString()

            if (metricBMI > 25) {
                binding?.tvStatus?.text = "Overweight"
                binding?.tvAdvice?.text =
                    "Go workout! also focus on nutrition to get the best results"
            } else if (metricBMI < 18) {
                binding?.tvStatus?.text = "Underweight"
                binding?.tvAdvice?.text = "Eat more! also Workout to get the best results"
            } else {
                binding?.tvStatus?.text = "Normal"
                binding?.tvAdvice?.text = "You can bulk and you can cut but don't go too far in any of the directions, its your call!"
            }
        }
    }

    private fun usBMI(){
        if(binding?.editTextWeight?.text!!.isEmpty() ||
            binding?.editTextWeight?.text.toString().toFloat() < 10 ||
            binding?.editTextHeight?.text!!.isEmpty() ||
            binding?.editTextHeight?.text.toString().toFloat() < 30){
            Toast.makeText(this@BMIactivity, "Please enter valid data",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }else{
            var usWeight = binding?.editTextWeight?.text.toString().toFloat()
            var usHeight = binding?.editTextHeight?.text.toString().toFloat()
            var usBMI = (((usWeight/ (usHeight*usHeight))*703)*100).roundToInt().toDouble() / 100
            binding?.tv1?.text = "YOUR BMI"
            binding?.tvBMI?.text = usBMI.toString()

            if (usBMI > 25) {
                binding?.tvStatus?.text = "Overweight"
                binding?.tvAdvice?.text =
                    "Go workout! also focus on nutrition to get the best results"
            } else if (usBMI < 18) {
                binding?.tvStatus?.text = "Underweight"
                binding?.tvAdvice?.text = "Eat more! also Workout to get the best results"
            } else {
                binding?.tvStatus?.text = "Normal"
                binding?.tvAdvice?.text = "You can bulk and you can cut but don't go too far in any of the directions, its your call!"
            }
        }
    }
```

```
activity_bmiactivity.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".BMIactivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_bmi_activity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/white"/>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rgUnits"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/drawable_radio_group_tab_background"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbMetricUnits"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:background="@drawable/drawable_unit_tab_selector"
            android:button="@null"
            android:checked="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="METRIC UNITS"
            android:textColor="@drawable/drawables_units_tab_text_color_selector"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbUSUnits"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:background="@drawable/drawable_unit_tab_selector"
            android:button="@null"
            android:checked="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="US UNITS"
            android:textColor="@drawable/drawables_units_tab_text_color_selector"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

    </RadioGroup>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutWeight"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:hintTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextWeight"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="WEIGHT (kg)"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutHeight"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:hintTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextHeight"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="HEIGHT (cm)"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#808080"
        tools:text="YOUR BMI"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="normal"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvBMI"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#808080"
        tools:text="25"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvStatus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#808080"
        tools:text="Normal"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="normal"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAdvice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#808080"
        tools:text="Go workout! also focus on nutrition to get the best results"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="normal"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCalculate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="CALCULATE"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[xml file preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUo6d.png)